# Complex R Shiny input binding issue with datatable

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny

I am trying to do something a *little bit* tricky and I am hoping that someone can help me.

I would like to add `selectInput` inside a datatable.
If I launch the app, I see that the inputs `col_1`, `col_2`.. are well connected to the datatable (you can switch to a, b or c)

*BUT* 
If I update the dataset (from `iris` to `mtcars`) the connection is lost between the inputs and the datatable. Now if you change a `selectinput` the log doen't show the modification. How can I keep the links?

I made some test using `shiny.bindAll()` and `shiny.unbindAll()` without success.

Any Ideas?

Please have a look at the app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(purrr)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput("data","choose data",choices = c("iris","mtcars")),
      DT::DTOutput("tableau"),
      verbatimTextOutput("log")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      dataset <- reactive({
        switch (input$data,
          "iris" = iris,
          "mtcars" = mtcars
        )
      })

      output$tableau <- DT::renderDT({
        col_names<-
          seq_along(dataset()) %>% 
        map(~selectInput(
          inputId = paste0("col_",.x),
          label = NULL, 
          choices = c("a","b","c"))) %>% 
          map(as.character)

        DT::datatable(dataset(),
                  options = list(ordering = FALSE, 
                          preDrawCallback = JS("function() {
                                               Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
                         drawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());
                         }")
          ),
          colnames = col_names, 
          escape = FALSE         
        )

      })
      output$log <- renderPrint({
        lst <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
        lst[order(names(lst))]
      })

    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Understanding your challenge:**

In order to identify your challenge at hand you have to know two things.

1. If a datatable is refreshed it will be "deleted" and build from
       scratch (not 100% sure here, i think i read it somewhere).
2. Keep in mind that you are building a html page essentially.

`selectInput()`is just a wrapper for html code. If you type `selectInput("a", "b", "c")` in the console it will return:

```
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" for="a">b</label>
  <div>
    <select id="a"><option value="c" selected>c</option></select>
    <script type="application/json" data-for="a" data-nonempty="">{}</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you are building `<select id="a">`, a select with `id="a"`. So if we assume 1) is correct after refresh you attempt to build another html element : `<select id="a">` with an existing id. That is not supposed to work: [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme). (Assuming my assumption 1) holds true ;))

**Solving your challenge:**

On first sight pretty simple: Just ensure the id you use is unique within the created html document.

The very quick and dirty way would be to replace:

```
inputId = paste0("col_",.x)
```

with something like: `inputId = paste0("col_", 1:nc, "-", sample(1:9999, nc))`.

But that would be difficult to use afterwards for you.

*Longer way:*

So you could use some kind of memory

1. Which ids you already used.
2. Which ones are your current ids in use.

You can use

```
  global <- reactiveValues(oldId = c(), currentId = c())
```

for that.

An idea to filter out the old used ids and to extract the current ones could be this:

```
    lst <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
    lst <- lst[setdiff(names(lst), global$oldId)]
    inp <- grepl("col_", names(lst))
    names(lst)[inp] <- sapply(sapply(names(lst)[inp], strsplit, "-"), "[", 1)
```

Reproducible example would read:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("data","choose data",choices = c("iris","mtcars")),
  dataTableOutput("tableau"),
  verbatimTextOutput("log")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  global <- reactiveValues(oldId = c(), currentId = c())

  dataset <- reactive({
    switch (input$data,
            "iris" = iris,
            "mtcars" = mtcars
    )
  })

  output$tableau <- renderDataTable({
    isolate({
      global$oldId <- c(global$oldId, global$currentId)
      nc <- ncol(dataset())
      global$currentId <- paste0("col_", 1:nc, "-", sample(setdiff(1:9999, global$oldId), nc))

      col_names <-
        seq_along(dataset()) %>% 
        map(~selectInput(
          inputId = global$currentId[.x],
          label = NULL, 
          choices = c("a","b","c"))) %>% 
        map(as.character)
    })    
    DT::datatable(dataset(),
                  options = list(ordering = FALSE, 
                                 preDrawCallback = JS("function() {
                                                      Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }"),
                                 drawCallback = JS("function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());
}")
          ),
          colnames = col_names, 
          escape = FALSE         
    )

})
  output$log <- renderPrint({
    lst <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
    lst <- lst[setdiff(names(lst), global$oldId)]
    inp <- grepl("col_", names(lst))
    names(lst)[inp] <- sapply(sapply(names(lst)[inp], strsplit, "-"), "[", 1)
    lst[order(names(lst))]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal, and these very clear explanations.
In fact, I already use the `rnorm` trick on the name of the created inputs.
It is a trick that quickly finds its limits. You have for example hacked the log system to simulate the right behavior.
Keeping these tricks forces me to do a lot of bypassing on everything I seek to build :(

Comment: ". In fact, I already use the rnorm trick on the name of the created inputs.". We can´t see that in the question,..(?). I´m afraid it only works with a workaround,..there were some similar questions in the past,.... Good luck anyway,....